# Asking user to input signed integer for UTM zone: bad idea?

Tags: utm, ux, user-interface

I need to ask my user some informations about the data he provided to my software, or the format in which he wants to export.

In particular I could have to ask which UTM zone (1 to 60, north or south) to use.

I am thinking of taking positive integers to be north zones, negative to be south zones.

Examples:

> 1 means UTM zone 1, north
>
> -1 means UTM zone 1, south

Is this a bad idea ? If not, does the meaning of the sign seems logic to you or should I swap it ? Do you know of any existing software that does use a signed integer to represent a UTM zone ?

The only alternative I am thinking of is to have two fields: one positive integer and one boolean (such as "isNorth").

Comment: There is no negative UTM zones and you shouldn't create them... I would never trust the information provided by a user that selected an impossible zone. It is also risky to ask the user to type a number (you can expect (nad) 83, (wgs) 84, a coordinate and all other kind of artistic input. The proper way would be to populate a drop down list with all the zones (1 N, 1 S, 2 N, 2 S .... 60 N, 60 S), or 2 lists (zones 1 to 60, and N/S). How you internally encode this information is irrelevant (negative values, text, zone+1000 etc, it is a programming issue, not a user issue anymore)

Comment: UTM is unsigned. Since it is based on longitude, a negative value would push me across the international dateline before south of the equator. As a UI issue, you should not create your own variations on representation. If the distinction between 1N and 1S is significant, the zone and direction should be two inputs, or a picklist that includes "1N", "1S", "2N",...

Comment: @vince, JGH thank you for your comments. I will take care of sanitizing user input and the ideal input indeed seem to be a drop down list (1N, 1S, 2N, 2S ... 60S).